# relación 1:N laravel, retorna vacio

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relaciones

Esto tratando de crear una relacion 1:N de mi tabla `usuarios` a una tabla `assigned_role` en laravel 5.6. Estoy usando la librería `Bouncer` para los roles y permisos.

Tengo mi modelo User con esta relacion:

```
public function roles()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\AssignedRoles', 'entity_id');
}
```

y mi modelo `AssignedRole` con estas relaciones, al usuario y al rol:

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'id', 'entity_id');
}
```

y

```
public function roleName()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'id', 'role_id');
}
```

y en mi controlador estoy tratando de extraer los roles de los usuarios así:

```
$employee = User::with('roles')->get();
```

cuando muestro la información de mis usuarios, se crea un array roles que siempre me aparece vacío:

```
Array([roles] => )
```

Alguien sabría decirme por favor que estoy haciendo mal¿? en la tabla assined_roles tengo esta columna: `entity_id` que identifica al usuario y se crean tantas entradas en esta como roles tenga el usuario. Por otro lado tengo la columna `role_id` que se relaciona con la tabla roles que es la que contiene el nombre del rol y más información...

Lo que pretendo hacer es algo así:

```
usuario rol
pepe, administrador
paco, tecnico
lolo, prueba...
```

así sucesivamente.

Gracias por leerme y la ayuda prestada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es una relacion de uno a muchos es asi

**model user**

```
public function roles()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\AssignedRoles', 'entity_id');
}
```

para traer una relación 1*n
*un usuario muchos roles*

```
$this->hasMany
```

el metodo belongsTo es para traer el valor de un id al que pertence lo cual es 1 a 1

asegurate de que tu modelo AssignedRoles tenga el nombre de la tabla correcta tambien